# puppeteer file chooser not working for me

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

```
const [fileChooser] = await Promise.all([
  page.waitForFileChooser(),
  page.click('#select-files-button'),
]);
fileChooser.accept("myVideo.mp4").then(console.log("done")).catch(console.error);
```

i am getting this error:-

> Error: a does not exist or is not readable
> at /rbd/pnpm-volume/912b4a42-7c8e-4d13-949c-5383de3b0d03/node_modules/.registry.npmjs.org/puppeteer/5.4.1/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/JSHandle.js:456:27

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
const [fileChooser] = await Promise.all([
  page.waitForFileChooser(),
  page.click('#select-files-button'),
]);

await fileChooser.accept(['myVideo.mp4']);
```

Also, make sure you use Puppeteer version 5.x